# Additional symmetries of the Traveling Salesman Polytope

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, traveling-salesman-problem

Given the complete graph $K_n=(V,E)$, the *[Traveling Salesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) Polytope* is a convex polytope in $\Bbb R^E$ obtained as the convex hull of the indicator vectors of (edge-sets of) Hamiltonian cycles in $K_n$.

- for $n=3$ it is a single point,
- for $n=4$ it is a regular triangle.

For $n = 5$ I found that the polytope has many more geometric symmetries than can be explained by the $5!$ automorphisms of $K_5$.
In fact, I found $2\cdot 6!=1440$ symmetries.

What about higher dimensions?

> **Question:** Have the symmetry groups and these "additional symmetries" of the Traveling Salesman Polytope been studied before? Where can I read about this?

Comment: Can you post some code that computes this? In particular, what is the structure of the group of order $1440$? Are you able to do this computation for $n=6$?

Comment: @verret My computations are still a bit sketchy. I constructed a subgraph of the edge-graph for which every symmetry extends to a symmetry of the polytope. For $n=5$ this is the [crown graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_graph) on 12 vertices (so its symmetry group should be $S_6\times S_2$). I just now finished the computation for $n\in\{7,8\}$ and I am a bit disappointed to find that their symmetry groups are just of size $n!$. It seems $n=5$ is exceptional. Anyway, if there is any literature that deals with the symmetries of the TSP polytopes I would be interested.

Comment: (There was a mistake in my deleted comment, it's not the double cover of $S_6$, but $S_6\times S_2$.)

Comment: I think an upper bound is given by the $2$-closure (in the sense of Wielandt) of $S_n$ acting on the cosets of $D_n$. It might be that a carefully chosen orbital graph already shows that we get $S_n$ in general.

Comment: Maybe the exceptional behavior for $n=5$ is due to two anomalies, one combinatorial and one group-theoretic.  In the complete graph $K_5$, the complement of a $5$-cycle is a $5$-cycle, which should explain the central $Z_2$.  The stabilizer of a point in the action of $S_5$ on $5$-cycles in $K_5$ is $D_{10}$, and the action of $S_5$ on the cosets of $D_{10}$ should extend to an action of $S_6$ on the cosets of a subgroup isomorphic with $A_5$, this last subgroup being transitive on six points.  I guess that this action gives the $S_6$, although I do not see why.

Comment: @verret It has been some time, but can you explain some of the intuition behind your last comment? Where does the 2-closure come from?

Comment: We construct a complete graph $X_n$ with labelled edges in the following way. The vertices of $X_n$ are the Hamiltonian cycles of $K_n$ and the edge between two vertices of $X_n$ is labelled with the number of edges that the two corresponding Hamiltonian cycles share.

For example, $X_4$ is the complete graph on $3$ vertices, with each edge labelled "2". 

If I am not mistaken, the automorphism group of the polytope is a subgroup of the automorphism group of $X_n$. (By automorphisms of $X_n$, I always mean label-preserving.)

Comment: My idea was to show that the automorphism group of $X_n$ is $S_n$, for $n\geq 6$. And it might suffice to consider certain subgraphs of $X_n$, for example, keeping only edges with a particular label. These will be orbital graphs for $S_n$ (in its action on cosets of $D_n$) but I'm not sure my comment about $2$-closure actually made sense.